# React API call error, resulting in blank screen

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks

I am new to programming and trying to build sample projects. could someone please help point me in the right direction on how to solve this issues of blank screen please?

Initially I had this

````
import CardApi from "./CardApi"

const ListApi = ({response, loading}) => {
  
     
    return (
        <div className="mx-2 mb-10">
            <h3 className="font-semibold text-xl text-slate-600">List API</h3>
            <div className="grid gap-4 md:grid-cols-3">
                {response && response.entries.map((api, index) =>  <CardApi />)}
    
            </div>
            </div>
      )
    }
    
    export default ListApi```

//but got console error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
````

```
//So read on some answers on here and updated to



`import CardApi from "./CardApi"

const ListApi = ({response, loading}) => {
  

  return (
    <div className="mx-2 mb-10">
        <h3 className="font-semibold text-xl text-slate-600">List API</h3>
        <div className="grid gap-4 md:grid-cols-3">
            {response && response.entries ?
            response.map((api, index) =>  (
            <CardApi /> 
            )) : null}

        </div>
        </div>
  )
}

export default ListApi
`
```

This time it flashes the data and api placeholder but still goes blank after a second
Error: response.map is not a function.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: To map over the `response` it should be an array. Could you share what the `response` value is and where it is coming from?

Comment: I am not sure what fixed it but I console logged it, could find the data in entries, removed the console log and somehow it worked. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

response.entries   should be an array

```
{response && response.entries && response.entries.length>0 && response.entries.map((api, index) =>  <CardApi />)}
```

Comment: You're not mapping over the entries

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were trying to map over `response.entries` but your updated code is attempting to map over the `response` object.

```
{response && response.entries ?
        response.map((api, index) =>  (
        <CardApi /> 
        )) : null}
```

should be

```
{response && response.entries ?
        response.entries.map((api, index) =>  (
        <CardApi /> 
        )) : null}
```

according to your original post